# PyQT5 - MAC OS - Set different icon for single window title-bar

Tags: macos, user-interface, pyqt5

I work on `python3` program with `GUI` built using `PyQT5`. All the windows have the black icon, but I want to have single icon to have a blue icon. How to do this? This is my code:

```
import sys

from PyQt5 import QtGui
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget


class BlackWindow(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 300, 220)
        self.setWindowTitle('Window with black icon')
        self.show()


class BlueWindow(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 300, 220)
        self.setWindowTitle('Window with blue icon')
        self.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon('./blue-icon.png'))  # this has no effect!!
        self.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon('./black-icon.png'))

    black_window_first = BlackWindow()
    black_window_second = BlackWindow()
    black_window_third = BlackWindow()
    blue_window_first = BlueWindow()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Looks like `QWidget`'s `setWindowIcon` method has no effect. Why is that? Is there perhaps any workaround? I am using MacOS El Capitan.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works for me on Ubuntu.  You might try setting the app to the blue icon to make sure it is valid.

When I put an invalid path in for the blue icon, I get the default, not the black icon.

Not the problem here, but I've seen slightly different code use the parent window's icon if the child was given an invalid icon.